# SQL GROUP BY insert not working - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-insert, correlated-subquery

I have a trigger after approving an item that triggers a look up and adds data to a new table. I am now getting "Subquery returned more that 1 value"

I have read other replies but nothing that addresses the issue broadly.. so I am with out answers at this time.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_BID_APROVAL] 
ON [dbo].[BID]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT BID_APPROVED FROM INSERTED) = 0 --if NO then do nothing else create and send purchase order
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END
    ELSE

    DECLARE @BIDDY_ID INT;
    SELECT @BIDDY_ID = BID_ID FROM INSERTED;

    DECLARE @SUPPY_ID TABLE(SUP_ID INT,BID_ID INT,PO_DATE DATE DEFAULT GETDATE());
    INSERT INTO @SUPPY_ID(SUP_ID, BID_ID)
        SELECT 
            SUP_ID,
            BID_ID
        FROM
            BIDLINE BL
        INNER JOIN 
            PRODUCTS P ON BL.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
        WHERE 
            BID_ID = @BIDDY_ID AND SUP_ID > 0
        GROUP BY 
            SUP_ID,BID_ID;

    INSERT INTO PURCHASE_ORDER (BID_ID, SUP_ID, PO_DATE)
        SELECT BID_ID, SUP_ID, PO_DATE 
        FROM @SUPPY_ID
END
```

[Current ERD for database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClbjF.png)

Comment: IF (SELECT top 1 BID_APPROVED FROM INSERTED)

Comment: Can you post your schema and a simple database?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement are all needed.

Comment: Atk.. i tried that already and no change to error

Comment: vy32, Gordon.. I am not sure where to add that on here..

Answer (score 0):

actually problem is in `if` condition we can change condition like this

```
IF (SELECT BID_APPROVED FROM INSERTED) = 0
```

To

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT BID_APPROVED FROM INSERTED where BID_APPROVED=0)
```

then it will works in your code